# css and js not found deployment laravel 6 shared hosting

Tags: laravel

I experienced problems when deploying laravel to shared hosting css and js files were not found, I uploaded the laravel file to public_html and changed server.php to index.php then moved the .htaccess which was in public to the public_html folder. I use this method to remove the public folder in the url.

[image: public]

[image: public_html]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Isnt `server.php` meant for development purposes? You should leave `index.php` fairly untouched (like this one https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php ), and have the directory root set to `/public` (or `/public_html` in your case) and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried to move the index.php file that was in public to public_html but why css and js blank https://i.ibb.co/86Z2b1q/Screenshot-3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with deploying your Laravel application to a shared hosting, consider watching [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4) on deploying to a shared hosting.

It covers most of what you need to do to correctly deploy to a shared hosting without too much trouble.

Hope this helps!